# Real vs Complex Interpolation

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis, interpolation, interpolation-theory

The two major classical interpolation theorems in analysis are [Riesz-Thorin Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem) (complex method) and [Marcinkiewicz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz_interpolation_theorem) (real method).

One can see the statements of the theorems and realize the differences between them (sublinearity, weak end-point estimates, and so on). I also know that these theorems can be extended to whole theories.

As far as I know, the complex method is called like so because in Riesz-Thorin Theorem it is neccesary that the scalar field is $\mathbb{C}$ (to use complex analysis tools). My questions are:

> Is there any real difference if the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? Isn't the scalar field of all $L^p$ spaces $\mathbb{C}$? (I can also define them over $\mathbb{R}$ but I cannot see the advantage).  Do I need my functions to be real-valued to use Marcinkiewicz? Can I use Riesz-Thorin to real-valued functions? What is the different between both interpolation methods in this aspect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any real difference if the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

No.

> Isn't the scalar field of all $L^p$ spaces $\mathbb{C}$?

Depends on context, not necessarily.

> Do I need my functions to be real-valued to use Marcinkiewicz?

No.

> Can I use Riesz-Thorin to real-valued functions?

Yes.

> What is the different between both interpolation methods in this aspect?

The terms complex and real interpolation don't refer to the scalar field.
They refer to the nature of proof.

[Marcinkiewicz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz_interpolation_theorem) is proven using real-variable methods, decomposing functions cleverly according to size, using sublevel sets, etc.

[Riesz-Thorin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem) is proven by a magic application of complex analysis, typically the proof uses Hadamard's three-lines lemma (which is a consequence of the maximum modulus principle).